# Первый запуск приложения

Tags: java, android

Наверное, глупый вопрос, но в интернетах ничего не нашел. (

Как узнать, что приложение запускается первый раз в следующих случаях случаях:

1. Первая установка и запуск.
2. Переустановка и первый запуск.

Comment: У меня хранятся данные в преференс,и мне нужно понять переустанавливалось ли приложение чтобы эти данные зачищать-дабы не было всяких конфликтов

Comment: Храни версию приложения в преференсах, если она отличается от текущей - значит обновляли...

Comment: Хм...вариант...
Чет туплю)))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Для проверки на первый запуск попробуйте использовать SharedPreferences. При первом запуске записываете в них любое значение, а потом проверяете его http://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/73-urok-33-hranenie-dannyh-preferences.html

Answer (score 3):

Например так:

1) Идём в гугл.

2) Вбиваем

> [how to detect first launch android](https://www.google.ru/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=how%20to%20detect%20first%20launch%20android)

3) В первой же [ссылке](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7217834/3212712) находим такой ответ:

Это можно сделать с помощью **SharedPreferences**. Т.е. при запуске приложения проверяем переменную типа **boolean**. Если её нет, значит первый запуск (или юзер удалял все данные приложения). После меняем значение переменной и при следующих запусках код запускаться не будет.

Код:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {

SharedPreferences prefs = null;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    prefs = getSharedPreferences("com.mycompany.myAppName", MODE_PRIVATE);
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    if (prefs.getBoolean("firstrun", true)) {
        // При первом запуске (или если юзер удалял все данные приложения) 
        // мы попадаем сюда. Делаем что-то
//и после действия записывам false в переменную firstrun
//Итого при следующих запусках этот код не вызывается.
        prefs.edit().putBoolean("firstrun", false).commit();
    }
}
}
```